# Create a matrix in R by changing the order of vector

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I am new user of R. I have two vectors in R and I want to put thses vectors in a matrix such as follows:

```
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)
    y = c(1.1, 2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 5.5)
    > m
         [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1  1.1
   [2,]    2  2.3
   [3,]    3  4.5
   [4,]    5  5.5
   [5,]    4  6.7
```

How can i do this in R?

Comment: How can I change the order of second vector in terms of first vector?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to join `x` with `y`, using `x` as an index for which value of `y` to take? i.e. - where `x` is `5`, take the `5`th value of `y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get there with:

```
cbind(x,y[x])


     x    
[1,] 1 1.1
[2,] 2 2.3
[3,] 3 4.5
[4,] 5 5.5
[5,] 4 6.7
```

Comment: (+1) aha, so indeed the values were rightly given. nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

If the x vector were not sequential you could still get success with:

```
cbind(x, y[order(x)] )
```